# How to set custom window height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Working on a project where objects move around the screen randomly. I'm trying to have a element at the top that does not get covered by these objects. This is my current code:

```
function makeNewPosition(){

    // Get viewport dimensions 
    var h = $(window).height() - 150;
    var w = $(window).width() - 100;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh,nw];    

}
```

This works well but I'm needing to block off, lets say 150px at the top of the screen where the objects cannot go. For some reason I have been unable to do this. How would I modify my code to accomplish this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just add those 150px as a base value to your random new height …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `150px` as offset from top. Otherwise the `bottom` 150px of your screen will be untouched by the objects, not the `top`.

```
function makeNewPosition() {
    var h = $(window).height() - 150;
    var w = $(window).width() - 100;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h) + 150;
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh,nw];    
}
```

If you want to let the left and right area of `100px` to be untouched too, you need to substract `200px` and add `100px` to the result.

```
function makeNewPosition() {
    var h = $(window).height() - 150;
    var w = $(window).width() - 200;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h) + 150;
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w) + 100;

    return [nh,nw];    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @eisbehr!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the 150 to your random height, that way no matter what the random number is generated your `nh` is going to start at least 150

```
var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h) + 150;
```